# Connect to wifi via c/c++ program

Tags: c++, c, linux, wifi

I'm searching on internet but I can't find anything about it.

Is there a way to do a scan for a wifi connection and to connect to one with a C/C++ program in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Wireless Tools for Linux](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Jean_Tourrilhes/Linux/Tools.html)

> The **Wireless Extension (WE)** is a generic API allowing a driver to
>   expose to the user space configuration and statistics specific to
>   common Wireless LANs. The beauty of it is that a single set of tool
>   can support all the variations of Wireless LANs, regardless of their
>   type (as long as the driver support Wireless Extension). Another
>   advantage is these parameters may be changed on the fly without
>   restarting the driver (or Linux).
>
> The **Wireless Tools (WT)** is a set of tools allowing to manipulate the
>   Wireless Extensions. They use a textual interface and are rather
>   crude, but aim to support the full Wireless Extension. There are many
>   other tools you can use with Wireless Extensions, however Wireless
>   Tools is the reference implementation.

You can interact with [NetworkManager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager) is via `DBus`.

Comment: I will take a look for sure. Just one thing if you can answer: do they provide some way to connect to wifi connections or is it just a scanning tool?